# min-height, não funciona em mobile o que faço?

Tags: html, css

estou desenvolvendo um site  desktop e mobile, porém quando estou no mobile, eu tenho que diminuir o height do slider no mobile certo, no entanto quando eu coloco min-height:250px !important, não vai , mesmo eu tentando  de todas as formas eu não consigo resolver veja o exemplo

Código desktop :

```
.banner ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    padding: 160px 0 110px;
    min-height: 506px !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

Código Mobile :

```
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
    .banner ul li {
         min-height:250px  !important;
         overflow:hidden;
         background-size: 100% 250px !important;
         box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    }
}
```

======

podem me dizer o que posso fazer  ?

Comment: O problema acontece no navegador do desktop também? (redimensionando a janela para ficar abaixo de 320px)

Comment: nao peixe, o problema só funciona com o  320px, quando eu tento colocar   esse código  min-height:250px !important; ele não obedece !

Comment: @EdwardJunior, coloca seu código no http://jsfiddle.net e posta o link aqui que fica mais fácil de testar.

Comment: ja consegui já galera VLW No código principal eu estava colocando !important,  estava dando conflito ja consegui vlw

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você possui uma condição para medias do tipo `screen`, da qual o mobile não faz parte. Remova esta condição, deixando desta forma:

```
@media (max-width:320px) {
    .banner ul li {
        min-height:250px  !important;
        overflow:hidden;
        background-size: 100% 250px !important;
        box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    }
}
```

---

Exemplo funcionando: http://jsfiddle.net/fcekLLLz/embedded/result/

Comment: Oeslei nada ! é o mesmo código mano -_-

Comment: Não é o mesmo, eu removi a condição `screen`. Tente colocar seu exemplo no jsfiddle como o André citou.

Comment: não resolveu em nada amigo !

Comment: vocês não entendem não tem nada a ver com o @media e sim com o código -_- media não tem nada a ver.

Comment: Por isso pedimos para que você coloque o código no jsfiddle. Fica mais fácil analisar com um exemplo real.

Comment: não tem como código muito grande !

Comment: @EdwardJunior adicionei um jsfiddle na resposta, e como pode ver, funciona. Não temos como lhe ajudar se não tivermos mais informações sobre o problema.

Comment: ja consegui era o !important, no condigo principal vlw Oeslei e André